# SwiftUI Context menu preview frame crashes when using in right to left environment

Tags: ios, swiftui, contextmenu

Besides the funny fliped text issue (which is NOT important in this question), The following code generates a weird transition when used with `. flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)` modifier:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyHStack {
                ForEach(0..<10) {
                    Text("Item \($0)")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        .background(Color.red)

                        .contextMenu {
                            Button("delete", role: .destructive) { }
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(true)
        .environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
    }
}
```

Take a look at this gif:

[image: Preview1]

I have tried to apply `.flipsForRightToLeftLayoutDirection(false)` to the:

- `Text` (after and before `.contextMenu` modifier
- `LazyHStack`
- And many other places and combinations with no luck.

How can I prevent these mysterious transitions?

Comment: Looks like internal bug

Comment: Are there any workarounds?

Comment: well... don't use standard context menu, but code something own, or file a bug to Apple and wait for fix.